# Spring Integration double poller

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have this xml configuration:

```
<int:annotation-config default-publisher-channel="messageChannel" />

<task:executor id="messageTaskExecutor" pool-size="1"
    queue-capacity="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
    <int:after-commit expression="@messageSessionStore.removeFromIdCache(headers.id.toString())" />
    <int:after-rollback expression="@messageSessionStore.removeFromIdCache(headers.id.toString())" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<bean id="messageQueryProvider"
    class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.channel.OracleChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider" />

<bean id="messageSessionStore"
    class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="channelMessageStoreQueryProvider" ref="messageQueryProvider" />
    <property name="tablePrefix" value="QUEUE_" />
    <property name="usingIdCache" value="true" />
</bean>

<int:channel id="messageChannel">
    <int:queue message-store="messageSessionStore" />
</int:channel>

<int:poller id="defaultPoller" fixed-delay="500" max-messages-per-poll="1" task-executor="messageTaskExecutor" default="true">
    <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED" synchronization-factory="syncFactory" isolation="READ_COMMITTED" transaction-manager="eosTransactionManager"/>
</int:poller>
```

And these 2 beans, one for the normal flow and one for the error flow:

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class NormalMessageHandler {

     @Autowired
     @Qualifier("errorChannel")
     private MessageChannel errorMessageChannel;

     @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "messageChannel")
     public void processMessage(final Message<?> message) {
     }
}

@MessageEndpoint
public class ErrorMessageHandler {
     @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
     public void handleFailedMessage(Message<Exception> message) {
     }
}
```

Now, I have 2 messages in my queue (in the db). I would expect them to be processed after each other, but it seems that somehow, this config leads to 2 seperate threads that trigger the normal message handling function (I can see this when I put a breakpoint in that function) for both messages at the same time. Am I missing something? I expected that the config of the task executor would lead to only 1 thread max. available for the message processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you have there `rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"`. That means if your task executor is too busy and there is no room to handle the task via its thread pool, the caller is responsible for that now.

Consider some other `RejectedExecutionHandler` implementation to use instead.
For example Spring Integration provides `CallerBlocksPolicy` implementation:

```
 * A {@link RejectedExecutionHandler} that blocks the caller until
 * the executor has room in its queue, or a timeout occurs (in which
 * case a {@link RejectedExecutionException} is thrown.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 3.0.3
 *
 */
public class CallerBlocksPolicy implements RejectedExecutionHandler {
```

Comment: If you just want one thread remove the task executor altogether and run the code on the poller thread. The next poll won't be scheduled until the current one completes.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I went with the option of Gary because there is no point to have a seperate (blocking) polling thread.